# Can 'go install' be made to work for executables with different names from the git repo?

Tags: go, goinstall

Go has a nice feature where you can `go install <x>` and it will download, build and install a binary.

For example, on my local windows PC, `go install github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser` will find the latest release for goreleaser, download, build and install it to my local binaries path.

I am working on a project where we would like to enable `go install`, but encounter a problem if the github repo name does not match the executable name. The GitHub CLI itself runs into the exact same problem:

Example:

```bash
go install github.com/cli/cli@latest
go: downloading github.com/cli/cli v1.14.0
go: github.com/cli/cli@latest: module github.com/cli/cli@latest found (v1.14.0), but does not contain package github.com/cli/cli
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

---

Update: I worked out that I could directly reference the package via it's sub directory. In my particular instance this works: `go install github.com/OctopusDeploy/cli/cmd/octopus@latest`

This is a bit unpleasant, but works correctly. It doesn't work for the github CLI because their go.mod has a `replace` directive in it :-(

Question: Can this be made nicer? Is there a way to put some sort of alias or configuration file so that `go install github.com/OctopusDeploy/cli@latest` can be used instead of `go install github.com/OctopusDeploy/cli/cmd/octopus@latest` ?

Comment: The only universal way to build a `main` package is to run `go install` or `go build` from within the module source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be made nicer? Is there a way to put some sort of alias or configuration file so that go install github.com/OctopusDeploy/cli@latest can be used instead of go install github.com/OctopusDeploy/cli/cmd/octopus@latest ?

No. Dead simple.